# How to Initialize Task Control Block Stack in C?

Tags: c, pointers, scheduled-tasks, rtos, freertos

I want to put a given task's initial program counter into the task's own stack.  This is so I can restore the stack context to begin running the task.

Does anyone have a good resource or know how to do this in C?

So far I've malloc'd a stack for a given task.

Here's an example I've found in assembly:

```
;program counter initialization for task2
    ldi r16, LOW(TASK2)
    sts TASK2_STACK_BEGIN, r16
    ldi r16, HIGH(TASK2)
    sts TASK2_STACK_BEGIN-1, r16
```

Where the low byte gets pushed onto TASK2's stack first, followed by the high byte.

Comment: It would be good to know why you are wanting to do this and what your goals for this functionality are.  Also would be good to know what the constraints are for this functionality.  A first cut would be to have a function that is called as the very first thing that a task does.  When the function is called, the return address is on the stack so you would just have to grab that address by looking back on what is on the stack.  However this sounds like some kind of operating system process management functionality.

Comment: The RTOS you are using takes care of this. You don't have to know these details.